# How to enter the 2nd-wave data into the same row that matches a previous session ID?

Tags: php, database, session

Because I am doing pretest and posttest online experiment. I need to enter the data of the posttest into the row with a same session ID in the pretest database based on different stimuli (or conditions) I assigned in the data set.

For example

The php of the first page of 2nd suvrey

```
<?
require_once 'config.sqlConnect.php';
//getting the id
$id = $_GET["id"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM newsblogstudy WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
//get the stimulus or condition, there are four conditions
$sti = $row[sti];
$sessionID = $row[sessionID];

session_start();
$_SESSION['sessionID'] = $sessionID;

print_r($_SESSION);

if ($sti == 1) {
    $webpage = "http://mediastudylab.com/onlinenews/webpages/newsblog-c1a.php";
} elseif ($sti == 2) {
    $webpage = "http://mediastudylab.com/onlinenews/webpages/newsblog-c2a.php";
} elseif ($sti == 3) {
    $webpage = "http://mediastudylab.com/onlinenews/webpages/newsblog-c3a.php";
} else {
    $webpage = "http://mediastudylab.com/onlinenews/webpages/newsblog-c4a.php";
}
?>
```

Then the same page I created a dynamic link

```
<a href="<? echo $webpage ?>"><input type="button" value="Go to the news blog"></a>
```

In the second page of posttest

```
<?
session_start();
$sessionID = $_SESSION['sessionID'];
print_r($_SESSION);
require_once 'config.sqlConnect.php';

$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

But the second page does not show sessionID the first time I use the browser. Later if I refreshed the page, it will works fine and the data goes to the exact row with the sessionID.
Each time I use the browser for the first time, the sessionID cannot be detected. But it will work in the same browser. It has nothing to do with session because each time before I try, i destroyed the session first. WHY??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think you have "space" symbols in your include file "config.sqlConnect.php" and there is issues with start session in your first file. Just try move session_start()  in your first file to first line

```
<?
session_start();
require_once 'config.sqlConnect.php';
//getting the id
```

And for future turn error_reporting level to E_ALL

Comment: if i put it at the beginning, it will start a new session with a new sessionID, right? I want to start a session with a sessionID that matches previous sessionID.

Comment: @Gemini for your code not important where you will start session.